# Отправить значение span на сервер

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-ui

Я подключил к странице библиотеку jquery-ui , и использую её функционал на странице. В частности autocomplete, автозаполнение инпута метками. (вот такая штука)

[image: скриншот]

сама метка представляет собой span со значением, внутри div, эти span'ы создаются на лету javasсript`ом , в исходной вёрстки их нет, вот код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){

            //Присоединяем автозаполнение
            $("#to").autocomplete({

                //Определяем обратный вызов к результатам форматирования
                source: function(req, add){

                    //Передаём запрос на сервер
                    $.getJSON("../../components/airports_search.php?callback=?", req, function(data) {

                        //Создаем массив для объектов ответа
                        var suggestions = [];

                        //Обрабатываем ответ
                        $.each(data, function(i, val){                              
                            suggestions.push(val.index);
                        });

                        //Передаем массив обратному вызову
                        add(suggestions);
                    });
                },

                //Определяем обработчик селектора
                select: function(e, ui) {

                    //Создаем форматированную переменную friend
                    var friend = ui.item.value,
                        span = $("<span>").text(friend),
                        a = $("<a>").addClass("remove").attr({
                            href: "javascript:",
                            title: "Remove " + friend
                        }).text("x").appendTo(span);

                    //Добавляем friend к div friend 
                    span.insertBefore("#to");
                },

                //Определяем обработчик выбора
                change: function() {

                    //Сохраняем поле 'Кому' без изменений и в правильной позиции
                    $("#to").val("").css("top", 2);
                }
            });

            //Добавляем обработчки события click для div friends
            $("#friends").click(function(){

                //Фокусируемся на поле 'Кому'
                $("#to").focus();
            });

            //Добавляем обработчик для события click удаленным ссылкам
            $(".remove", document.getElementById("friends")).live("click", function(){

                //Удаляем текущее поле
                $(this).parent().remove();

                //Корректируем положение поля 'Кому'
                if($("#friends span").length === 0) {
                    $("#to").css("top", 0);
                }               
            });
        });
    </script>
```

А вот сам форма отправки:

```
<div id="searchform">
    <label id="toLabel">Индекс Аэропорта:</label>
        <div id="friends" class="ui-helper-clearfix" >
    <input id="to" type="text" name="index_icao_en">
    </div>
    ....(тут еще календарь, пару чекбоксов, но вопрос не про них)
</div>
```

Span`ы появляються внутри div id="friends"
Выглядят они вот так. (значение и ссылка удалить)

```
      <span>UEBB<a class="remove" href="javascript:" title="Remove UEBB">x</a></span>
```

Вопрос в том как передать значения span на сервер по кнопке Отправить ,желательно post запросом?

Comment: перед отправкой формы пройтись по спанам, сгенерить хидден инпуты и прицепить их к форме. Если вам требуется отправить их вместе с формой, конечно. Если отдельно, то просто аяксом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В обработчике `submit` формы пройдитесь по вашим `span`-ам и сгенерируйте скрытые инпуты, которые добавьте к форме.

Самой формы у вас вообще почему-то нет, но допустим что она выглядит следующим образом. В конец формы мы добавили див для добавляемых инпутов.

```
<form action="/script.php" method="POST" id="searchform">
    <label id="toLabel">Индекс Аэропорта:</label>
    <div id="friends" class="ui-helper-clearfix" >
          <input id="to" type="text" name="index_icao_en">
    </div>
    ....(тут еще календарь, пару чекбоксов, но вопрос не про них)

    <div id="ldata"></div>
</form>
```

Далее напишем функцию для их генерации

```
function preparedata(){
    $("#ldata").empty();
    var tpl = '<input type="hidden" name="labels[]">';

    $("#friends span").each(function(){
         $(tpl).val( $(this).text() ).appendTo("#ldata");
    });

    return true;
}
```

и вызовем ее при отправке формы

```
$("#searchform").submit(function(){
     return prepareData();     
});
```

чтобы предотвратить отправку формы (например если метки не выбраны) то надо вернуть `false`.

---

В целом, если вам просто надо оправить метки аякс-запросом, то следует банально сформировать массив, и отправить его

```
 var data = $("#friends span").toArray().map(function(v){ return $(v).text(); })
 $.post("script.php", { labels: data });
```

зы: замечу, что

- метод `live` давно устарел, используйте `on`
- несколько странным выглядит использование `getElementById` при наличии jquery.
- не используйте относительные пути а-ля `../..`
- `$("<a>").addClass("remove").attr({ href: "javascript:"}).text("x")` серьезно надо все это в коде генерить? `$('<a class="remove" href="#">x</a>')` куда более наглядно и продуктивно.

Comment: Подскажите как подключить Ваш код к странице?, не получается, в ldata не появляются инпуты

Comment: @Dmitriy вы див то на форму заменили? или какая форма у вас отправляется по итогу при нажатии на Отправить? возможно там и ошибка где то у меня синтаксическая, я же не тестировал код нигде. проверьте что в консоли.

Comment: Вот код   $("#messageForm").submit(function(){
                            return preparedata();     
                       });

Comment: #messageForm , айдишник самой формы

Comment: я просто вставил функцию и её вызов в <script type="text/javascript"> , у вас только в вызове было return prepareData(); а функция называется preparedata(), я написал маленькими буквами

Comment: в консоле ошибок нет

Comment: Если запускаю ваш скрипт в консоле и жму отправить, все работает как надо

Comment: @Dmitriy не понял, как вы его запускаете?

Comment: Большое спасибо , я разобрался, все заработало , нужно было обернуть код в $(function(){ });